# ios would my app be rejected if not all functions are provided for reivew

Tags: ios

My app provides some e-books and the books can have texts, images, audios and videos. Now it is about to be submitted to apple and I need to prepare some book data for apple to review. The problem is currently we do not have any audios or videos, so the content provided would only contain texts and images, which means apple cannot review audio content or video content. Would this be rejected by apple because they cannot review all the functionalities the app has?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's honestly no way to tell if your app will get accepted until you just submit and see what they have to say. Worst case scenario is the reviewer rejects this version and tells you exactly what they want you to fix. And it could potentially be rejected for reasons you truly didn't expect.

I do know that they will reject apps where buttons, navigation, links, etc just do not work. But to me, the bottom line is there's no risk in submitting it and just seeing what they say.